# Create permission to users to create list item, but don't read it

Tags: list, permissions

I must create a permission level for users to add list items, but not read the list item in the list.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

their are two methods:

1. Use Powershell to create new permission level which have Add items but no View items.

   $spweb=Get-SPWeb -Identity "";

   $spRoleDefinition = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleDefinition;

   $spRoleDefinition.Name = "Submit only";

   $spRoleDefinition.Description = "Can submit/add forms/files/items into library or list but cannot view/edit them.";

   $spRoleDefinition.BasePermissions = "AddListItems, ViewPages, ViewFormPages, Open";

   $spweb.RoleDefinitions.Add($spRoleDefinition);

   $spweb.Dispose();

http://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/add-only-permission-level-in-sharepoint-2010/

2. 2nd method is: create 2 lists(one list with give user permissions to add items and on 2nd list no permission to end user), than adding the code in the item added event of the first list to add item to another list and than remove it from the first list.

Comment: First solution works Great. Thank You Very much :)